# getting variable from while loop

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Okay, I think what I've got is pretty simple for an experienced web dev person. Right now, this [this](http://stateofdebate.com/debatelist.php) is the index page for State of Debate, my debate website. From the code below, you can see that I have a while loop to echo out each debate, which corresponds to a "did" in the mySQL database. What I need to do, for upvote/downvote purposes, is to get each "did" that goes through the loop. I would then pass it to the "upvote.php" and "downvote.php".

I've tried a foreach loop, although that could be the answer and I just didn't find it. I've used $_SESSION['did'] = $row['did'] and all that does is pass the last did to the PHP page.

Any help is appreciated. And please ask if you need more info.

```
<?php



$result = mysql_query("SELECT did,debatetitle  FROM debates");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td><a href='/debatepage.php?did=" . $row['did'] . " '>" . $row['debatetitle'] . "</a></td>";
?>







<tr><td>
<a href="upvote.php" onClick="alert('You have given this item a thumbs up! You can change your vote, or leave it how it is.')"; onMouseOver="return changImage()" onMouseOut= "return changImageBack()" ><img
name="jsbutton2" src="Graphics/thumbs-up-unclicked.jpeg" width="75" height="75" border="0"
alt="javascript button"></a>

<script type="text/javascript">
function changImage()
{
document.images["jsbutton2"].src= "Graphics/thumbs-up.jpeg";
return true;
}
function changImageBack()
{
 document.images["jsbutton2"].src = "Graphics/thumbs-up-unclicked.jpeg";
 return true;
}
</script>


<a href="downvote.php" onClick="alert('You have given this item a thumbs down! You can change your vote, or leave it how it is.')"; onMouseOver="return changeImage()" onMouseOut= "return changeImageBack()" ><img
name="jsbutton1" src="Graphics/thumbs-down-unclicked.jpeg" width="75" height="75" border="0"
alt="javascript button"></a>

<script type="text/javascript">
function changeImage()
{
document.images["jsbutton1"].src= "Graphics/thumbs-down.jpeg";
return true;
}
function changeImageBack()
{
 document.images["jsbutton1"].src = "Graphics/thumbs-down-unclicked.jpeg";
 return true;
}
</script>

</tr></td>




<?php
echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: I'd really like to help, but I am deterred by those masses of code... please be specific and post only as much code as necessary and as little as possible. You'll get more and better help. Cheers

Comment: Cheers to you. supajason was able to figure it out.

Comment: Of course you are right and do not need any feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change this:

```
<a href="upvote.php" onCli....
```

to

```
<a href="upvote.php?did<?PHP echo $row['did']"; ?> onCli
```

and the same with downvote link.

To use the variable in upvote.php:

```
<?PHP
echo $_GET['did'];
?>
```

Comment: Got it. Thanks for that! I've been looking for the solution to this for a long time. Now, when I want to use it as a variable on the other page, what do I do (sorry, I'm new to PHP)?

Comment: OOOPS sorry was typing fast and forgot to add ; ?> see updated answer.